# How do I expose my extended field to the API?

Tags: orocommerce

I've started using OroCommerce, and wanted to try to extend a native OroCommerce entity to add a field to it.

For testing purposes, I've tried adding a "testField" field to the Product entity.

So I've created a migration class following the documentation, and that works fine:

```php
class ExtendNativeMigration implements Migration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema, QueryBag $queries)
    {
        $table = $schema->getTable("oro_product");
        $table->addColumn('testField', "string", [
            "oro_options" => [
                "extend" => ["owner" => ExtendScope::OWNER_CUSTOM]
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

I now have a "testField" column in the oro_product table.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to be able to expose that newly-created field to  the API.

I created the api.yml file in my bundle, and tried something like this:

```yaml
api:
  entities:
    Oro\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Product:
      fields: 
        testField:
          exclude: false
```

But the field doesn't appear when I call the products API. I've tried other things in the api.yml file, but to no avail.

The field appears when I dump the API config, but it simply says "null":

```
...
    exclusion_policy: all
    fields:
        testField: null
        skuUppercase:
            exclude: true
...
```

I'm probably doing something wrong here, but I'm not sure what.

Can I have some pointers on how to do this correctly? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine. I've checked it locally, and the field is added to API with no issues.

1. Make sure you have run `php bin/console oro:api:cache:clear -eprod` command after updating the API YAML configuration.
2. Also, if you are working with the storefront API, you should use `api_frontend.yml` instead of api.yml file.

Comment: Ah, thank you! The problem is that I was calling the file `api.yml` instead of `api_frontend.yml`.